# Edit Topics, when tags only match a specific version?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I found a lot of topics on SO where tags are only for a specific version, for example: `ruby-ob-rails3`.

I ignore a few tags, including `ruby-ob-rails`. Should I add a non-specific tag for these topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore all RoR tags, you can use a wildcard in the ignored tag to ignore all tags that start with `[ruby-on-rails]`.

Try this: `ruby-on-rails*`.

Far as editing the questions to add a more generic tag goes... I don't think it really matters. I probably wouldn't - it'd be a neverending battle to get every question that needs it tagged appropriately.

Comment: I didn't know that this also works, really nice, thanks!